# Bootstrap cols (flex-nowrap) take more space then parent when child element has overflow:hidden and word-spacing:no-wrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row flex-nowrap" style="overflow: hidden;">
            <div class="col" style="flex: 0 0 120px !important; padding-right: 0 !important;">
                <h1>Title</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <p style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem commodi debitis et, exercitationem
                    expedita illo voluptate! Aliquam architecto atque distinctio fugit in natus officia quos! Ipsa ipsum
                    non quidem vitae!</p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">1</div>
                    <div class="col-6 text-right">2</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The first col should have a fixed width, that's why i use `flex: 0 0 120px`. The p-tag has `overflow:hidden` and `word-spacing:no-wrap` to make the text only appear on 1 line, hiding any text that overflows the container. I then have a row, with 2 column's in it, to place some text in them (number 1 and number 2) at the bottom of that col, so it says 1 in the bottom left, and 2 on the bottom right.

The problem is that because the p-tag have `overflow:hidden` and `word-spacing:no-wrap` the whole parent element is overlapning the container, causing the number 2 to be invisible. See this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Luzb78ej/)

What am I doing wrong? Any way to fix this?

Comment: Yes exactly like that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your `overflow:hidden` to parent element of your paragraph - it must be a block or inline block element with width property defined or limited somehow (by size of the parent or `max-width`).

https://jsfiddle.net/esr4Lvo7/

version with `text-overflow: ellipsis` here: https://jsfiddle.net/esr4Lvo7/1/